# Garage insulation questions

Tags: insulation, garage

I am looking to add some insulation to my garage. The ceiling is fully insulated, but only the back half of the walls are. The front half is just bare studs with the exterior wall.  Our main bedroom is above the garage, and I'm thinking that adding insulation to these gaps will help.

My main question is trying to decide between batts or rolled insulation, because some of the gaps for my studs are very short (~10") so I'm just unsure which product will be easier to work with. Additionally, do I need faced or unfaced for my garage walls? I tried looking up the codes for my county but I couldn't find anything that specified this. I'm thinking faced because it allows me to attach to the walls easier.

Comment: My prefer way is unfaced and poly vapour barrier, since I feel that stops more air drafts, than faced.  Faced is nice if the studs are 1/2 or an inch wider than the batts.

Comment: @crip659, I sneak the poly staples up onto the side of the framing instead of stapling to the bottom edge.